# unable to send email from linux CentOS 7 using postfix

Tags: email, zoho, sasl, mailx

I fire the following command to send out an email.

```
echo "This is the body of the email." | mailx -s "Subject of the Email" -r "Emailadmin@digiklug.com" knowyrtech@gmail.com
```

Below are my logs:

tail -f  /var/log/maillog

```
Oct 14 19:34:50 SGGS-Prod postfix/pickup[2065215]: 39FCB48B3BA: uid=0 from=<Emailadmin@digiklug.com>
Oct 14 19:34:50 SGGS-Prod postfix/cleanup[2065227]: 39FCB48B3BA: message-id=<652aed5a.MSgmspqvsdKAT5tU%Emailadmin@digiklug.com>
Oct 14 19:34:50 SGGS-Prod postfix/qmgr[2065216]: 39FCB48B3BA: from=<Emailadmin@digiklug.com>, size=479, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 14 19:34:51 SGGS-Prod postfix/smtp[2065218]: warning: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found
Oct 14 19:34:51 SGGS-Prod postfix/smtp[2065218]: 39FCB48B3BA: to=<knowyrtech@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.zoho.com[136.143.190.56]:587, delay=1.5, delays=0/0/1.5/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.zoho.com[136.143.190.56]: no mechanism available)
```

Below is the configuration file:

```
$ cat /etc/postfix/main.cf
relayhost = [smtp.zoho.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain, login
```

Created `smtp_sasl_password_maps` using the below command:

```
[smtp.zoho.com]:587    Emailadmin@digiklug.com:my-password
sudo chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Can you please suggest?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
[smtp.zoho.com]:587    Emailadmin@digiklug.com:my-password
```

to

```
smtp.zoho.com   Emailadmin@digiklug.com:my-password
```

and following the below steps helped resolve the issue.

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```